# replace value with 1 and apply SUM method in one query SQL

Tags: sql, replace, casting, google-bigquery, sum

I need to replace the value in column `imp` from `1-0` to `1` and sum it up. Column `imp` is a STRING, so it also needs to be converted to INT. Each line represents the record so I need to sum up `imp` and group by another column (in order to get the number of records for a specific Advertiser)
My data looks like this:

```
advertiser       advertiser_id          imp
Frank            123                    1-0
Frank            123                    1-0
Mike             124                    1-0
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    a.AdvertiserID as AdvertiserID,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN a.imp = '1-0' THEN "1"
        END
    ),
    b.advertiser_name as AdvertiserName,
FROM
    (
        `bigquery_table_a` a
        INNER JOIN `another_bigquery_table` b ON (a.AdvertiserID = b.advertiser_id)
    )
GROUP BY
    AdvertiserID,
    AdvertiserName
```

Error message: `No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: STRING`
Desired output:

```
advertiser       advertiser_id         imp
Frank            123                    2
Mike             124                    1
```

Comment: maybe you have other string values in the imp column that your case/when does not handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for aggregation and `count()`?

```
SELECT AdvertiserID, AdvertiserName, COUNT(*)
FROM `bigquery_table_a` a JOIN
     `another_bigquery_table` b
     ON (a.AdvertiserID = b.advertiser_id
GROUP BY AdvertiserID, AdvertiserName;
```

Or, if you specifically want to count values of `'1-0'`, use `COUNTIF()`:

```
SELECT AdvertiserID, AdvertiserName, COUNTIF(imp = '1-0')
FROM `bigquery_table_a` a JOIN
     `another_bigquery_table` b
     ON (a.AdvertiserID = b.advertiser_id
GROUP BY AdvertiserID, AdvertiserName;
```

Comment: Oh that's right. No need to convert it to int and replace it. Easier to use COUNTIF. The data is consistent, so I can get away with this. Perfect. Thank you, I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem with your code is that *as you point out* you want an `INTEGER` type so you can sum it;.  Yet your `CASE` goes out of its way to return a `STRING` type instead.  So you could change

```
CASE
        WHEN a.imp = '1-0' THEN "1"
END
```

to

```
CASE
        WHEN a.imp = '1-0' THEN 1
END
```

You might also want to add an `ELSE` condition, but honestly that isn't likely to matter for your purpose; if you did, it would look like

```
CASE
        WHEN a.imp = '1-0' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
END
```

Now there also may be simpler ways to get the count you want; what else you might do depends what DBMS you're using.  But from where you are, the above seems like the simplest fix.